# PHP string replace with multiple conditions

Tags: php, regex, string, str-replace

I would like to make a replace on a string where I have to have multiple conditions and do the replace based on them. I know I can use array as search string in str_replace() but my problem is that a part of the string is dynamic.

For example:

the string would look like this:

```
<p>SOME TEXT</p> 
<p>SOME TEXT (dynamic content 1)</p> 
<p>SOME TEXT (dynamic content 2)</p> 
<p>SOME TEXT</p>
```

and the replaced string should look like this

```
<p>SOME <span>TEXT</span></p> 
<p>SOME <span>TEXT (dynamic content 1)</span></p> 
<p>SOME <span>TEXT (dynamic content 2)</span></p> 
<p>SOME <span>TEXT</span></p>
```

As the example shows the search words are `TEXT` and `TEXT (dyn cont)` my problem is that I can't figure out how do I set the condition for the second search word where the content is dynamic between the brackets.

Basicly if there were 2 constant words than I would do something like this:

```
if(strpos($str, 'TEXT') !== FALSE || strpos($str, 'TEXT ()') !== FALSE){
  echo str_replace(array('TEXT', 'TEXT ()'), 
                   array('<span>TEXT</span>', '<span>TEXT ()</span>'),
                   $str);
}
else {
  echo $str;
}
```

but obviously this doesn't works in this case.

How can I make this work?

Comment: regexes would do the trick. str_replace can't match wildcards, so unless you do a bunch of searching/locating first, you can't use str_replace for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex for matching:

```
(?:<p>SOME\s)(TEXT\s?.*?)(?:<\/p>)
```

The single capture group should get `TEXT` and anything after it up until the `</p>`

Additionally, if you want to allow that dynamic content to contain newlines, change the regex to this:

```
(?:<p>SOME\s)(TEXT\s?[\s\S]*?)(?:<\/p>)
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gQ4lZ9/1)

Comment: Thank you! I modified your expression a little bit and than did a `preg_replace()`. Now everething is ok.